# Finding an angle within an 80-80-20 isosceles triangle Duplicate

Tags: geometry

[image: 1]

This question is weird, because I asked some of my friend and my teacher to solve this and they couldn't answer or they had different answers (20° , 30° , 40° & lots of different number)

Comment: It is a famous problem, the answer is $30^\circ$. see [Langley's adventitious angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%27s_Adventitious_Angles)

Comment: There are many well known angle chasing problems in $80$-$80$-$20$ triangles.  See here - https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToClassical.shtml